# Language strings in .resx-files or Redis?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, redis, webforms

I am trying to model a new site (only on paper so far), and I started to think about what might be the best approach. The site needs to be multi-lingual (at least two languages). Since I recently began testing Redis, I figured that maybe I could store a library of languages in Redis instead of in .resx-files.

I know it's doable, but is it worth it? Is it possible it will increase performance, or are strings in .resx-files already cached and performant "enough"? I lack the experience of how .resx-files are processed, so all your input is of help!

Comment: I am wondering about the same question. Have you found an answer? What solution have you chosen?

Comment: I have taken the simplest route for my project. I store all the languages and language strings in the regular sql-database. When I request a certain string from my language service, that service questions redis (my app-cache) for the language string, and if not found, the service fetches the string from sql and pushes it to the cache (like almost any other sql-database object requested).

Comment: How do you update your translations when releasing? Do you run some queries to add the new strings? Or do you use a separate database for the translations and use it both for dev and production? Or have you found a better solution?

Comment: The translations live in the normal database, so they will be add/removed via sql when necessary. I thought that was the easiest for my project.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently worked on a multilingual web site. 
I used a Json string.
I'm storing in the database one string per language.

{
"HeaderWordWideShipping" : "Word Wide Shipping / 30 days Full Return", 
"HeaderCurrency" : "Currency" , 
"ComboSelectAll" : "Select all..."
}

On Page_Init I select from database the correct string and I assign values to public properties. here some sample code (I used Newtonsoft.Json.dll to read Json):

```
public string PagetxtHeaderWordWideShipping { get; set; }
public string PagetxtHeaderCurrency { get; set; }
public string ComboSelectAll { get; set; }
string pageTextsMaster = my json string reteived from db

pageTextsMaster = pageTextsMaster ?? @"{"""":""""}"; //if pageTextsMaster isNull then I set an empty Json string.

    JObject o = JObject.Parse(pageTextsMaster);

    PagetxtHeaderWordWideShipping = (string)o.SelectToken("HeaderWordWideShipping", false); //Setting false will not throw an exception if the required value is not found
    PagetxtHeaderCurrency = (string)o.SelectToken("HeaderCurrency"); //false is default so I do not have to repeat it.
    ComboSelectAll = (string)o.SelectToken("ComboSelectAll");
```

then you can use public propertis in your page.
to be extra safe I added a coalesce operator to replace a null with a default language text:

```
<h3><%: PagetxtHeaderWordWideShipping ?? "Word Wide Shipping / 30 days Full Return"%></h3>
```

Comment: Did you really use json with Redis? I was more thinking about a library like booksleeve (and maybe protobuf for serialization).